# iPhone 6 Plus cannot add calendars

Tags: ios, calendar, iphone

On an iPhone 6 Plus the calendar app will not allow me to add calendars nor edit calendars.  The "+" sign is grayed out!  What can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can't add calendars in the Calendar app, only in Settings. To add an event, you should have a calendar set up in Settings.

If you do have calendars set up, make sure they are visible by going to the Calendars button at the bottom center in the Calendar app. Select "Show All Calendars" and see if you can now add events.

If you don't have a calendar set up, go to the Settings app, then iCloud, and make sure you enabled Calendars. Or you can add your own calendars from Outlook, Gmail etc. at Settings -> Mail, Contacts, Calendars -> Add Account.

Let us know if you succeeded. :)